# Removing a Partial View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a View with Name, CreatedDate, Address, etc. In the Address section I have State, City etc. I made this section a Partial View.

By default there will be one address section in mainView. I have a button "AddAddress". I want to add another address section if user clicks the button (add a partial view). After getting this partial view there should be a remove button to remove this partial view. I am not using Razor.

the following code is my Javascript to delete my address.

```
        function deleteAddress(addressId, clientId) {
            var url1 = "/Client/DeleteAddress";
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this address?")) {
                var result = false;
                $.ajax({
                    url: url1,
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    data: { AddressId: addressId, ClientId: clientId },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        result = data;
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("XMLHttpRequest=" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + "\ntextStatus=" + textStatus + "\nerrorThrown=" + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
                if (result) {
                }
            }
        }
```

the following code is in my controller.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult DeleteAddress(int AddressId, int ClientId)
    {
        if (AddressId != 0)
        {
            if (ClientId != 0)
            {
                ClientService.Client clientVuTemp = new ClientService.Client();
                clientVuTemp = (ClientService.ClientView)TempData["EditClientData"];

                clientVuTemp.Address.RemoveAt(AddressId);
                //soft delete
                clientVuTemp.Address[AddressId].IsActive = false;
                _clientSvc.InserOrUpdateClientAddresses(clientVuTemp.Address);
            }
            else
            {

            }
            return Json(true);
        }
        else
            return Json(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Model we can have a property like `IsAddAddressEnabled`, Onclick on AddAddress you can set this as true and onclick on cancel you can set as false.

In View you can put an condition,

```
@if(Model.IsAddAddressEnabled)
{
    Html.Partail(....)
}
```

Comment: i want to do this using ajax/javascript.page shud not postback

Comment: OK, you can do the similar operation but just get the view as JsonResult and update the view with the content